# Impossible multi-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, c99

I was reading some introductory material on programming in C.
The following example was presented:

```
int matrix[][] = {{ 1,2,3}, {5,6,7}};
```

As gcc (7.5.0 in my case) and clang (6.0.0 in my case) did not compile, I tried several C standards (c89, c90), but none worked.

Is there a C standard version in which this is valid?

Comment: ***`I was reading some introductory material on programming in C. The following example was presented`*** I would suggest another C book or tutorial.

Comment: `f2003` is not even a C standard. It's Fortran!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your syntax :

```
int matrix[][] = {{ 1,2,3}, {5,6,7}};
```

here, in `C language` you need to declare the size of all the dimensions except the `first one(which is optional)`, and here you didn't declared the `second dimension`, so obviously it will give you a `syntax error` as it is not valid in `C`.

If we take a variable `x`, then in a `generalized form` we can say that the `correct syntax` is :

```
int matrix[][x] = {{1,2,3,...., x terms}, {1,2,3,....,x terms},.... upto your desired no. of terms};
```

and for your array :

```
int matrix[][3] = {{1,2,3},{5,6,7}};
```

Some examples for your reference are given below :

```
int matrix[] = {1,2,3};
int matrix[][4] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}};
int matrix[][4][5] = {{1,2},{3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11}};
int matrix[][5][3] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11},{12,13,14}};
```

Now, let's come to your last question:

`Is there any version of standard C which allows to do so?`

Answer is: `No!` there is `no such version` of `C` currently available which allows us to do so. It is a `strict syntax convention` that you `should follow`.

I hope so this explanation was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

It is not legal in C. The error message is self-explanatory:

> declaration of 'matrix' as multidimensional array must have bounds for
> all dimensions except the first

you need to provide all the sizes except the first:

```
int matrix[][3] = {{ 1,2,3}, {5,6,7}};
int matrix[][2][3] = {{{ 1,2,3}, {5,6,7}}, {{ 1,2,3}, {5,6,7}}};
/* etc etc*/
```

> Is there a C standard version in which this is valid?

NO

Answer (score 0):

C was designed to allow for the possibility of single-pass processing.  Given a declaration like:

```
int foo[][4] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}};
```

a compiler could start placing things in memory as it read them.  When it finds the first close brace, it would know that it needs to insert space before the 4 because it would know that it had output 3 values but the inner dimension was 4.  Had the construct instead been:

```
int foo[][] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}};
```

the compiler would have no way of knowing that space would be needed after the 3 until after it had read the 7, by which point it would have already written the values 1 through 6 into consecutive storage locations.  While it's possible that some implementations could conceivably use multi-pass scanning so they could extend the language to accommodate such constructs, I would not expect any compiler vendor to expect the benefits to justify the cost.